# Area of triangle in a different coordinate system.

Tags: triangles, area

This is for an android application but I think it is too mathematical to put on normal SO.

I have a coordinate system where the origin is (0, 0), and the x and y axis go from -1 to 1. This coordinate system represents my screen.

I have 3 vertices in the system that represent a triangle and I would like to calculate the area of the triangle.

I first calculate the length of every line and then I use Heron's formula to calculate the area.

The problem is, the area I get is for the coordinate system -1 to 1 in the x and y, with a 0 ,0 origin. However, I would like the area of the triangle in terms of my actual screen dimensions. What is the most efficient way I can convert the area?

I was thinking I might be able to do something with the aspect ratio of my screen but I just don't know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the area scaled up to your screens size.
Here are the constants used

$A$: the area of the triangle in the coordinate system
$w_s$: the width of the screen
$w_c$: the width of the coordinate system
$h_s$: the height of the screen
$h_c$: the height of the coordinate system

Then this is the area of the triangle scaled to your screen
$$A\times\frac{w_s}{w_c}\times\frac{h_s}{h_c}$$

Comment: Please see my edit, I tried your solution but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Thats odd, it seems to work if I divide by 4 at the end. Why is that? maybe it's just for this case

Comment: @Clay Please see my edit

Comment: The thing is, I don't know where the origin for my screen will be. Sometimes it's in the centre, sometimes it starts at the top left. Would this equation still work if I just said $A * screenHeight * screenWidth / 4$ ?

Comment: @Clay I have edited the answer, now it should be easy to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works very nicely :D